# Programmatically creation of Tax Classes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to include different types of Taxes in different classes to be assigned to the products. Unfortunately with the code below I put all the taxes at the standard rate and so I have no way to assign them later to the products.

[image]

The problem is that I am unable to create new Additional Tax Classes in a programmatic manner.

```
$tax_data = array(
   'tax_rate_country' => '*', 
   'tax_rate_state' => '*', 
   'tax_rate' => $tax_rate, 
   'tax_rate_name' => $tax_rate_name, 
   'tax_rate_priority' => 1, 
   'tax_rate_compound' => 0, 
   'tax_rate_shipping' => 1, 
   'tax_rate_order' => 0, 
   'tax_rate_class' => $tax_rate_class
);

$tax_rate_id = WC_Tax::_insert_tax_rate( $tax_data );
WC_Tax::_update_tax_rate_postcodes($tax_rate_id, wc_clean('*'));
WC_Tax::_update_tax_rate_cities($tax_rate_id, wc_clean('*'));
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's not working for you because _insert_tax_rate is "for internal use only", even if it's a public function (?!?). Maybe someone could help us?

Answer (score 2):

```
$tax_class_name = 'GST-15';
$tax_class_slug = 'gst-15';
$tax_rate = 8;
$tax_rate_name = 'SGST';

// Create tax classs
$tax_class = WC_Tax::create_tax_class($tax_class_name,$tax_class_slug);

//Invalidate the cache

WC_Cache_Helper::invalidate_cache_group( 'taxes' );
WC_Cache_Helper::get_transient_version( 'shipping', true );

//Attached the tax_rate to tax_class
$tax_rate_data = array(
    'tax_rate_country' => '*',
    'tax_rate_state' => '*',
    'tax_rate' => $tax_rate,
    'tax_rate_name' => $tax_rate_name,
    'tax_rate_priority' => 1,
    'tax_rate_compound' => 0,
    'tax_rate_shipping' => 1,
    'tax_rate_order' => 0,
    'tax_rate_class' => $tax_class_slug
);

$tax_rate_id = WC_Tax::_insert_tax_rate( $tax_rate_data );
```

Comment: It would be good if you included a brief explanation of the code and why it solves the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a function, which I reduced to a skeleton here, which works for me.

```
$tax_classes = "";

foreach( $taxes_list as $tax ) {
    $tax_information_id = $tax->KODE->__toString();
    $tax_classes .= sanitize_title( $tax_information_id ) . "\n";
}

if ( get_option( "woocommerce_tax_classes" ) ) {
   update_option( "woocommerce_tax_classes", $tax_classes );
}

foreach( $taxes_list as $tax ) {
    $tax_data = array(
      'tax_rate_country' => '*',
      'tax_rate_state' => '*',
      'tax_rate' => $tax["vat"],
      'tax_rate_name' => $tax["name"],
      'tax_rate_priority' => 1,
      'tax_rate_compound' => 0,
      'tax_rate_shipping' => 1,
      'tax_rate_order' => 0,
      'tax_rate_class' => sanitize_title( $tax["code"] )
  );

   $tax_rate_id = WC_Tax::_insert_tax_rate( $tax_data );
   WC_Tax::_update_tax_rate_postcodes($tax_rate_id, wc_clean('*'));
   WC_Tax::_update_tax_rate_cities($tax_rate_id, wc_clean('*'));
 }
```